# Legenda de boxplot de média e mediana na função ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, gráfico

Estou tentando adicionar uma legenda identificando que a "bola" é a média e a "linha" é a mediana do gráfico de boxplot da seguinte maneira:

```
mediasCon1 = tapply(dados$FS, dados$Trat, mean)

boxplot(dados$FS ~ dados$Trat, data = dados, col="gray", 
        xlab = 'Tratamentos', ylab = 'Espermatozoides - Cauda Solta')
points(1:3, mediasCon1, col = 'black', pch = 16)
legend("topleft", legend=c("Média", "Mediana"),
       lty=c(NA,1), col="black", lwd=1:3, bty="n", pch=c(16,NA))
```

[image]

No entanto, ao usar a função ggplot2, o seguinte erro aparece:

```
ggplot(data=dados, aes(x=Trat, y=FS)) + geom_boxplot(fill=c("#DEEBF7","#2171B5","#034E7B"),color="black") +
  xlab('Tratamentos') +
  ylab('Espermatozoides - Cauda Solta') + 
  stat_summary(fun=mean, colour="black", geom="point", 
               shape=18, size=5) + 
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 20),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 16)) +
legend("topleft", legend=c("Média", "Mediana"),
       lty=c(NA,1), col="black", lwd=1:3, bty="n", pch=c(16,NA))

Error in strwidth(legend, units = "user", cex = cex, font = text.font) : 
  plot.new has not been called yet
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `legend` só funciona com `plot`, daí o erro. O ggplot2 usa funções e sintaxe próprias, e tem como princípio não permitir (ou dificultar muito) qualquer ação que leve à visualizações potencialmente enganosas, o que é o caso de inserir uma legenda independente. Nele, legendas são geradas à partir das estéticas e geometrias; para mapear a média e a mediana para legendas, precisa adicionar geometrias correspondentes, controlando a aparência (*shape* e *linetype*) através de escalas.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Species, Sepal.Width)) +
  stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = .33) +  # se quiser os limites no formato "barra de erro"
  geom_boxplot(width = .66) +
  stat_summary(aes(linetype = "mediana"),
               geom = "errorbar",
               fun.ymin = median, fun.ymax = median,
               width = .66, size = 1) +
  scale_linetype_manual(NULL, values = 1) +
  stat_summary(aes(shape = "média"),
               geom = "point",
               fun.y = mean,
               size = 5) +
  scale_shape_manual(NULL, values = 18) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "largura da sépala") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OBS: Como a pergunta não depende dos seus dados, usei um conjunto de dados do R como exemplo.

Comment: Obrigado Carlos!!!!!!