# Metade do boxplot aparecendo na função ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, gráfico, plot

Estou fazendo um boxplot usando o pacote ggplot2, porém, por algum motivo externo, apenas metade do boxplot está sendo feito para os tratamentos "Controle" e "IMD comercial".

Veja abaixo que ao fazer o gráfico usando a função "boxplot", o gráfico normalmente é feito.

```
mediasCon = tapply(dados$CS, dados$Trat, mean)
boxplot(dados$CS ~ dados$Trat, data = dados, col="gray", 
        xlab = 'Tratamentos', ylab = 'Espermatozoides - Cabeça Solta')
points(1:3, mediasCon, col = 'Red', pch = 16)
```

[image]

No entanto, ao fazer o mesmo gráfico usando a função GGPLOT2, veja que para os primeiros dois tratamentos apenas metade do gráfico está sendo feito, por que isso está ocorrendo?

Além disso, como adiciono "caudas" de boxplot usando a função ggplot2?

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=dados, aes(x=Trat, y=CS)) + geom_boxplot(fill=c("#DEEBF7","#2171B5","#034E7B"),color="black") +
  xlab('Tratamentos') +
  ylab('Espermatozoides - Cabeça Solta') + 
  stat_summary(fun=mean, colour="black", geom="point", 
               shape=18, size=5) + 
                     theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 20),
                     axis.text = element_text(size = 16))
```

[image]

Comment: Veja [minha resposta para sua pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/475451/117168), ela mostra como adicionar as caudas. Mas no caso dos seus dados, por conta da assimetria, elas irão coincidir com as caixas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os boxplots não estão aparecendo pela metade. Os dados tem uma assimetria bastante acentuada, o que faz algumas estatísticas se confundirem. Por exemplo, a variável CS tem o mínimo e o primeiro quartil idênticos para o controle, enquanto seus terceiro quartil e máximo são iguais para o IMD Comercial.

```
library(tidyverse)

dados %>% 
  split(.$Trat) %>% 
  map(summary)
## $Controle
##      Trat                Rep             CS            FD             FS      
##  Length:4           Min.   :1.00   Min.   :0.0   Min.   :0.00   Min.   :0.00  
##  Class :character   1st Qu.:1.75   1st Qu.:0.0   1st Qu.:0.00   1st Qu.:0.75  
##  Mode  :character   Median :2.50   Median :0.0   Median :0.50   Median :2.00  
##                     Mean   :2.50   Mean   :0.5   Mean   :0.75   Mean   :2.00  
##                     3rd Qu.:3.25   3rd Qu.:0.5   3rd Qu.:1.25   3rd Qu.:3.25  
##                     Max.   :4.00   Max.   :2.0   Max.   :2.00   Max.   :4.00  
##        FE       
##  Min.   : 9.00  
##  1st Qu.: 9.75  
##  Median :10.50  
##  Mean   :11.25  
##  3rd Qu.:12.00  
##  Max.   :15.00  
## 
## $`IMD Comercial`
##      Trat                Rep             CS             FD            FS     
##  Length:4           Min.   :1.00   Min.   :0.00   Min.   :0.0   Min.   :2.0  
##  Class :character   1st Qu.:1.75   1st Qu.:0.75   1st Qu.:0.0   1st Qu.:3.5  
##  Mode  :character   Median :2.50   Median :1.00   Median :1.5   Median :5.0  
##                     Mean   :2.50   Mean   :0.75   Mean   :1.5   Mean   :4.5  
##                     3rd Qu.:3.25   3rd Qu.:1.00   3rd Qu.:3.0   3rd Qu.:6.0  
##                     Max.   :4.00   Max.   :1.00   Max.   :3.0   Max.   :6.0  
##        FE       
##  Min.   :14.00  
##  1st Qu.:14.00  
##  Median :16.00  
##  Mean   :16.25  
##  3rd Qu.:18.25  
##  Max.   :19.00  
## 
## $`IMD Princ\xedpio Ativo`
##      Trat                Rep             CS            FD            FS    
##  Length:4           Min.   :1.00   Min.   :1.0   Min.   :1.0   Min.   : 1  
##  Class :character   1st Qu.:1.75   1st Qu.:1.0   1st Qu.:1.0   1st Qu.: 1  
##  Mode  :character   Median :2.50   Median :1.5   Median :2.5   Median : 6  
##                     Mean   :2.50   Mean   :1.5   Mean   :2.5   Mean   : 6  
##                     3rd Qu.:3.25   3rd Qu.:2.0   3rd Qu.:4.0   3rd Qu.:11  
##                     Max.   :4.00   Max.   :2.0   Max.   :4.0   Max.   :11  
##        FE      
##  Min.   : 9.0  
##  1st Qu.: 9.0  
##  Median :13.5  
##  Mean   :13.5  
##  3rd Qu.:18.0  
##  Max.   :18.0
```

Comment: Obrigado! Mas porque na função "boxplot" o gráfico se apresenta de maneira dissimilar ao executado pela função "ggplot"?

Comment: @BrenoG. a documentação do geom_boxplot diz que o cálculo para os extremos do boxplot é levemente diferente da função do r base e que isso pode ficar aparente em conjuntos de dados pequenos, como parece ser caso.